# HSV filter with slider not updating from default when sliders changed

Tags: python, opencv

Everything with this is working except the fact the GUI sliders seem to be doing nothing.

I'm applying the `hsv_filter` in main main.py and setting up the GUI with a separate class.

If a filter is not supplied, it should be controlled by the GUI trackbars, but if a filter isn't supplier I get the error `NameError: name 'hsv_filter' is not defined`

```
# limestone HSV filter
hsv_filter = HsvFilter(0, 100, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0)

loop_time = time()
while(True):

    # get an updated image of the game
    screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()

    # pre-process the image
    processed_image = vision_limestone.apply_hsv_filter(screenshot, hsv_filter)

    # do object detection
    rectangles = vision_limestone.find(processed_image, 0.85)

    # draw the detection results onto the original image
    output_image = vision_limestone.draw_rectangles(screenshot, rectangles)

    # display the processed image
    cv.imshow('Matches', output_image)
```

And this is where I'm creating the GUI.

```
# create gui window with controls for adjusting arguments in real-time
    def init_control_gui(self):
        cv.namedWindow(self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv.resizeWindow(self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 350, 700)

        def nothing(position):
            pass

        # create trackbars for bracketing.
        # OpenCV scale for HSV is H: 0-179, S: 0-255, V: 0-255
        cv.createTrackbar('HMin', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 179, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('SMin', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('VMin', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('HMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 179, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('SMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('VMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)
        # Set default value for Max HSV trackbars
        cv.setTrackbarPos('HMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 179)
        cv.setTrackbarPos('SMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 255)
        cv.setTrackbarPos('VMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 255)

        # trackbars for increasing/decreasing saturation and value
        cv.createTrackbar('SAdd', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('SSub', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('VAdd', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)
        cv.createTrackbar('VSub', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW, 0, 255, nothing)

    # returns an HSV filter object based on the control GUI values
    def get_hsv_filter_from_controls(self):
        # Get current positions of all trackbars
        hsv_filter = HsvFilter()
        hsv_filter.hMin = cv.getTrackbarPos('HMin', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.sMin = cv.getTrackbarPos('SMin', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.vMin = cv.getTrackbarPos('VMin', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.hMax = cv.getTrackbarPos('HMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.sMax = cv.getTrackbarPos('SMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.vMax = cv.getTrackbarPos('VMax', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.sAdd = cv.getTrackbarPos('SAdd', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.sSub = cv.getTrackbarPos('SSub', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.vAdd = cv.getTrackbarPos('VAdd', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        hsv_filter.vSub = cv.getTrackbarPos('VSub', self.TRACKBAR_WINDOW)
        return hsv_filter

    # given an image and an HSV filter, apply the filter and return the resulting image.
    # if a filter is not supplied, the control GUI trackbars will be used
    def apply_hsv_filter(self, original_image, hsv_filter=None):
        # convert image to HSV
        hsv = cv.cvtColor(original_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        # if we haven't been given a defined filter, use the filter values from the GUI
        if not hsv_filter:
            hsv_filter = self.get_hsv_filter_from_controls()

        # add/subtract saturation and value
        h, s, v = cv.split(hsv)
        s = self.shift_channel(s, hsv_filter.sAdd)
        s = self.shift_channel(s, -hsv_filter.sSub)
        v = self.shift_channel(v, hsv_filter.vAdd)
        v = self.shift_channel(v, -hsv_filter.vSub)
        hsv = cv.merge([h, s, v])

        # Set minimum and maximum HSV values to display
        lower = np.array([hsv_filter.hMin, hsv_filter.sMin, hsv_filter.vMin])
        upper = np.array([hsv_filter.hMax, hsv_filter.sMax, hsv_filter.vMax])
        # Apply the thresholds
        mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
        result = cv.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=mask)

        # convert back to BGR for imshow() to display properly
        img = cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

        return img

    # apply adjustments to an HSV channel
    def shift_channel(self, c, amount):
        if amount > 0:
            lim = 255 - amount
            c[c >= lim] = 255
            c[c < lim] += amount
        elif amount < 0:
            amount = -amount
            lim = amount
            c[c <= lim] = 0
            c[c > lim] -= amount
        return c
```

It seems to be taking the default and never updating.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a logical problem in your code.

Inside the infinite while loop, you are passing `hsv_filter` to the `vision_limestone.apply_hsv_filter()` function. Here the `hsv_filter` passed is defined just before the while loop as:

```
# limestone HSV filter
hsv_filter = HsvFilter(0, 100, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0)
```

Now look at the initial lines of the `apply_hsv_filter()` function:

```
def apply_hsv_filter(self, original_image, hsv_filter=None):
    # convert image to HSV
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(original_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # if we haven't been given a defined filter, use the filter values from the GUI
    if not hsv_filter:
        hsv_filter = self.get_hsv_filter_from_controls()
```

Here, if `hsv_filter` is not passed to the function, it takes values from the trackbar. As you are always passing `hsv_filter` to this function, it is never reading values from the trackbar.

Comment: That's half of it explained, that make sense @Rahul thank you. The other half of the issue is the fact changing the track bar does nothing to the displayed image. It never updates from the default values.

Comment: I cannot see a "waitKey" after "imshow" function. Make sure you have a `cv.waitKey(1)` line after imshow function inside the while loop.

Comment: if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break

is at the bottom, I cut it out of the OP